# gethostbyname_r() calls for non-resolvable hosts always returning with h_errnop set to TRY_AGAIN (on Ubuntu 19.04 and 20.04)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, hostname, gethostbyname

```
    while(do_again) {

       rc = gethostbyname_r(host, &hbuf, tmp, TMPLEN, &hp, &my_h_errno);
       if (rc != 0) {
          if(my_h_errno == TRY_AGAIN) {
             printf("HOST NOT FOUND: got a TRY_AGAIN response from gethostbyname_r()\n");
             continue;
          } else if (my_h_errno == HOST_NOT_FOUND) {
             printf("HOST NOT FOUND: Got an authoritative answer\n");
             exit(0);
          } else {
             printf("Other errors..\n");
             exit(0);
          }
       }
       do_again = false;
    }
```

Above code always returning with `my_h_errno` set to `TRY_AGAIN` for non-resolvable hostnames on Ubuntu 19.04 and 20.04. On previous versions of the OS or on other Linux flavors, it usually returns a more authoritative version, `HOST_NOT_FOUND`.

How does the call(`gethostbyname_r`) exactly work? And are there any changes on the dns or lookup mechanism on the latest versions of Ubuntu which is causing such behavior?

Answer (score 1):

[Update]
Installing libnss-myhostname which kind of acts as a fallback mechanism for hostname resolving, fixed the issue.

Debugging on the glibc code got me to the point where there was a call to the above library functions, if exsits, where the h_errno was set to HOST_NOT_FOUND for non-resolvable hosts. That was initially being set to TRY_AGAIN in the glibc's gethostbyname_r functionality for such cases.

Comment: Thanks it works. I was facing this issue for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

From the manual

> The gethostbyname*(), gethostbyaddr*(), herror(), and hstrerror()
> functions  are  obsolete.  Applications should use getaddrinfo(3),
> getnameinfo(3), and gai_strerror(3) instead.

Comment: Thanks @kjohri. But getaddrinfo(3) was also resulting in the same issue, as I guess that function was also implemented with almost the same functionality as of gethostbyname(), except that they added support for ipv6 addresses.